# Multilanguage support for android application

Tags: java, android, database, performance, android-layout

I am developing an android application in which the user requirement is to have that app in multi language. I need to know which is the best way to do so.

1. By storing the languages(string.xml) in a folder. For eg: For french in a folder named as value-fr.
2. By storing all labels and respective languages in a Db table and retrieving those on    different language selection.

From the above two method which is the best way to be done considering the app performance.

Comment: the option 1 isthe best way to do it, no need to create DB for it !!

Comment: Okay fine. but what if i have deployed my application on playstore and the users are using it, and in the meantime , we need to give user a new language support. How would we update that res folder in the users apk. Do we need to make a new release of that application?

Comment: yes, make the changes in the app and also change the app version in manifest and upload it again.

Comment: note that the resources will only be updated if language setting (system level) changes. If you want only this app to use a different language, you'll have to use another method.

Comment: why not just use a http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to go for the resources folder by storing all the languages of French in the `res/values-fr` folder and reflect it all over the application.

By following the resources way you do not need to bother about managing the each and everything in your application flow. The application will be directly changed according to the `French` language as the user will change its language to french. It will directly access all the resources from the `value-fr` folder if you have kept.

If you will go by database way then in that case you are supposed to check for the locale and you will have to manage all the values of your application according to the local each and everytime which will lead you to complexity of handling resources.

So, Why not go for the best way if android is providing you such great functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can do either way, but the best way is option 1. i.e. By storing the languages(string.xml) in a folder like values-Fr. Using this will allow android to do the handling automatically instead of you telling database which is the current locale you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the different folder in the `res` to support your application in multiple language.

Android handle all the things automatically, it picks the string resources from that file which is your current language of the device.

Answer (score 0):

Just playing the Devil's Advocate - Android only supports ISO 639-1 (2-letter) codes at this point, Java 7 which supports [ISO 639-2](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) (the three-letter language codes) is not natively supported by the device's framework for resource directories.

If your requirements expect you to adhere to the three letter language codes set in the standard than you may have to look elsewhere for this support (be it an in-house solution or another third party solution).